# Angular 2- How to refresh HTML after updating flag value of component?

Tags: angular

I am working ton angular 4.  I have basic structure of my app is like this.

**AppComponent.ts**

```
<app-header></app-header>


<router-outlet ></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Now, i have a problem here.my menu bar is in headrer component that loads only once in my project. i want to change some menu bar items on run time.for that purpose i have set flag in header.component.ts.

Now, from that component where i want to change menu bat, i call the function of headercomponent.ts which set the value of flag. i successfully call the function and it also update the value of flag. but html did not changes.

Here is my **headercomponent.ts** function which set value of flag.

```
 setflag()
  {
    alert("sadads")
    this.flag=true


    console.log(this.flag)
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    this.ref.reattach();
  }
```

and here is HTML part in **headercomponent** that i want to update.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li ><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Log in</a></li>

                      <li><a [routerLink]="['/register']">Sign up</a></li>
                      <li *ngIf="flag==true"><a [routerLink]="['/register']">Dashboard</a></li>

                    </ul>
```

and from **homecomponent.ts** i am calling this function like this.

```
import {HeaderComponent} from "../header/header.component";
  providers: [HeaderComponent]

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,private comp: HeaderComponent) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.comp.setflag();
}
```

this will call the function from header and change the value of flag. but that change value will not invoke changes in html.

Can any body tell me, how can i update html in headercomponent in this scenario.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: by default if component has public member - the html should automatically refresh itself after the changes. So - in your case - you should make "flag" public member of HeaderComponent

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in your component file, no need of ChangeDetectorRef. In Angular 2 change detection is automatic. Define class level variable flag and set Boolean value

**headercomponent.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent {

flag = false

setflag()
  {
    alert("sadads")
    this.flag=true
  }
}
```

**Plunker**
[Plunker here...](https://plnkr.co/edit/kL8Pee32XN7u7ofNxtBx?p=preview)

If u want to update flag from other components then use service

```
**Service**
@Injectable()
export class FlagService {
  flag = false;

  toggleFlag() {
   this.flag = !this.flag;
 }
}

export class HeaderComponent {

 flag: boolean;

 constructor(private flagService: FlagService) {
  this.flag = this.flagService.flag;
}

}
```

Comment: but its not updating HTML

Comment: Please find the plunker. It's working https://plnkr.co/edit/kL8Pee32XN7u7ofNxtBx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. i will do it

Comment: If you want to change the flag from some other component then u can use service to communicate between components.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do you want is using a service. It's not complicated it's simply write

```
//shared service
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    myVariable:any;
}
```

After, in your component, use this services to get the value of myVariable. You can use "getter" and "setter" if you want

```
 //Any component
  @Component({..})
  export class MyComponent {
    get myVariable()
       return this.dataService.myVariable;
    }
    set myVariable(value)
       this.dataService.myVariable=value;
    }
    constructor(private dataService: DataService){ }

    myFunction()
    {
        this.myVariable="Hello World";
        //or 
        this.dataService.myVariable="Good By"
    }
  }
```